# Rails and Bootstrap SASS tutorials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

i'm looking for recommendations for learning bootstrap-sass with rails 4, I haven't had much luck and would like to know what people think.

I've looked at some Lynda videos but they are using it to organically create sites not with rails, is it the same thing? Is it easy enough to integrate bootstrap like this?

Comment: Bootstrap has great examples, maybe just start messing around...

Comment: Try the [rails composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) script. It will create a project with bootstrap enabled in an interactive way, so you can check how they integrate and have a rails4-boostrap example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "RailsApp" of rails composer script.

Here is the start up application with [Rails Composer Gem](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer).

Very useful and nicely documented:

For Rails [Bootstrap SASS Tutorial](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap)